# How to check the destination value for null in automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, automapper

I have an object in which some fields are already filled in. I would like to only fill in the fields that don't matter when mapping to another object using AutoMapper. Could you help with that? Thank you in advance

I tried to do so, but it didn't help:

*CreateMap<StatusLevelDTO, StatusLevel>()
.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember, destMember) => destMember != null));*

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateMap<StatusLevelDTO, StatusLevel>() .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember, destMember) => destMember == null ? DoSomethingWhenTrue : DoSomethingWhenFalse));
```

*I would like to only fill in the fields that don't matter when mapping to another object using AutoMapper.* was a sentence that I did not understand, hence pseudoCode.